# How to fix in Tailwindcss div height overflows parent div

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, tailwind-css

My card element has a fixed height of `h-80` (in Tailwind). usually I use the card in a grid.

Now, I have a div inside that card, which is bigger than it's parent div, however I want it to scroll vertically.
The problem becomes now, that I can not scroll completly down. The last line is cut off.

**Overflow auto, but not completly scrollable:**
[image: Overflow-auto but not to the end]

**Full height to see what content is missing:**
[image: Full height to see the full content]

I am using VueJS as framework, this is my Card component:

```
  <div class="w-full overflow-hidden h-full px-3 py-2">
    <div v-if="title" class="block text-gray-700 text-lg font-semibold py-2 px-2">
      <i :class="title_icon" />
      {{ title }}
    </div>
    <div class="h-full overflow-y-auto">
      <slot>
        <-- Here is another component which holds the appointments-->
      </slot>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**How do I fill the remaining space in a div with overflowing content in TailwindCSS?**

Comment: Not an height issue as my brain told me seconds after I posted the question.... See the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `flex-grow` property on the sub-div to allow it to grow.
Set `flex` on the parent div and `flex-col` to keep the styling.
Find the documentation [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-grow#class-reference)

```
  <div class="flex flex-col w-full overflow-hidden h-full px-3 py-2">
    <div v-if="title" class="block text-gray-700 text-lg font-semibold py-2 px-2">
      <i :class="title_icon" />
      {{ title }}
    </div>
    <div class="flex-grow h-full overflow-y-auto">
      <slot>
        <-- Here is another component which holds the appointments-->
      </slot>
    </div>
  </div>
```